# How do I find out what AWS actions do I need to grant for a CLI command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Consider I want to run some AWS CLI command, e.g. `aws s3 sync dist/ "s3://${DEPLOY_BUCKET_NAME}" --delete`.

How do I know what specific permissions (actions) do I need to grant in order for this command to work correctly? I want to adhere to the least privileged principle.

---

Just to clarify my question. I know where to find a list of all actions for S3 or other service and I know how to write a policy. The question is how do I know what **specific** actions do I need to grant for some CLI command?

Because, each command will use different actions and the arguments of the command also play a role here.

Comment: You'll definitely need to study documentation for this. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-with-s3-actions.html

Comment: I've updated my question to clarify it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Almost every command used in the AWS CLI map one-to-one to IAM Actions.

However, the `aws s3` commands such as `sync` are higher-level functions that call multiple commands.

For `sync`, I would imagine you would need:

- `ListBucket`
- `CopyObject`
- `GetObjectACL`
- `PutObjectACL`

If that still doesn't help, then you can use **AWS CloudTrail** to look at the underlying API calls that the AWS CLI made to your account. The CloudTrail records will show each API call and whether it succeeded or failed.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about this approach, but could you, please, elaborate on how I can analyze the CloudTrail logs to find the list of actions?

Comment: After running the `aws s3 sync` command, go to the CloudTrail console. It will display the recent API calls to your account (it might take a few minutes to come through). You can then examine each of those calls and see whether the calls were permitted or denied.

Answer (score 1):

There's no definitive mapping to API actions from high-level awscli commands (like `aws s3 sync`) or from AWS console actions that I'm aware of.

One thing that you might consider is to enable CloudTrail, then temporarily enable all actions on all resources in an IAM policy, then run a test of `aws s3 sync`, and then review CloudTrail for what API actions were invoked on which resources. Not ideal, but it might give you something to start with.

You can use [Athena to query CloudTrail Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/cloudtrail-logs.html). It might seem daunting to set up at first, but it's actually quite easy. Then you can issue simple SQL queries such as:

```
SELECT eventtime, eventname, resources FROM trail20191021 ORDER BY eventtime DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about this approach, but could you, please, elaborate on how I can analyze the CloudTrail logs to find the list of actions?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know for S3 specifically, that is documented in the S3 Developer Guide:

- [Specifying Permissions in a Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-with-s3-actions.html)
- [Specifying Conditions in a Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/amazon-s3-policy-keys.html)
- [Specifying Resources in a Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-arn-format.html)

In general, you can get what you need for any AWS resource from [Actions, Resources, and Condition Keys for AWS Services](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_actions-resources-contextkeys.html)

And you may find the [AWS Policy Generator](https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html) useful